# Selenium chromedriver not working on mac?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to learn the basics of Selenium for a couple days now, and I have kept running into the same roadblock.

The error :

> Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

keeps appearing despite the fact that the chromedriver and my python code are in the same folder. Is there any way to fix this? The code I am running is here:

```
    import time
    from selenium import webdriver

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
    driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
```

Comment: _"keeps appearing despite the fact that the chromedriver and my python code are in the same folder."_ - that is not what the error message is telling you to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can add `executable_path` to your `webdriver.Chrome()` declaration and provide the full path of where `chromedriver.exe` is located:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/path/to/chromedriver.exe")
```

The string in `executable_path` will need to be replaced with whatever the absolute path in your system is to the `chromedriver` executable.